# Retrieve 100th order date of each customer

Tags: sql

I have an order table with the following info

| customer | order_id | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | 11234 | 2021-01-01 |
| Customer 1 | 11235 | 2021-05-10 |
| Customer 1 | 11236 | 2021-10-01 |
| Customer 2 | 11237 | 2022-01-01 |
| Customer 2 | 11238 | 2022-01-10 |
| Customer 3 | 11239 | 2022-07-01 |

I need to write a query that returns one row for each customer and the date that each customer made their 100th order (100_order_date). There are some customers with less than 100 orders and some customers with more than 100 orders. For customers with less than 100 orders, I am indifferent if the 100_order_date column is null or there is not a row for that customer.

Comment: do you count their order or not? if yes what's the row name ? is ```order_id``` AUTO_INCREMENT or not ?

Comment: tag with database, and show some attempt

Comment: This will heavily depend on the database you’re working in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by customer order by order_date, order_id) as rn
    from T
)
select customer,
    /* returns all customers but with null values */
    min(case when rn = 100 then order_id end) as order_id,
    min(case when rn = 100 then order_date end) as order_date 
from data
group by customer;
```

To get rid of the "non-100" customers:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by customer order by order_date, order_id) as rn
    from T
)
select customer, order_id, order_date from data
where rn = 100;
```